# Passing Jinja2 macro parameters via list/dictionary

Tags: templates, macros, arguments, parameter-passing, jinja2

I have a Jinja2 macro with multiple parameters. I would like to set these parameters using a list or a dictionary, e.g. something like this:

```
{% macro mymacro(foo, bar) -%}
foo: {{ foo }}
bar: {{ bar }}
{%- endmacro %}

{% set args=[1, 2]  %}

{{ mymacro(args) }}
```

Expected output:

```
foo: 1
bar: 2
```

However, this does not work, because the list in `args` is assigned to `foo` entirely, while `bar` stays empty.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply use the [`*` operator](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists) to unpack the list `args` into arguments. It's a python operator but apparently Jinja2 supports it too even though it is undocumented.

```
{% macro mymacro(foo, bar) -%}
foo: {{ foo }}
bar: {{ bar }}
{%- endmacro %}

{% set args=[1, 2]  %}

{{ mymacro(*args) }}
```

Comment: as well as `**kwargs` for keyword arguments